# Splitting the outputs of a 7.1 USB sound card into 4 distinct stereo pairs

Tags: audio, alsa

My plan is to use the 4 analog outputs of my 7.1 USB sound card (AUREON XFIRE 8.0 HD) as individual stereo pairs to create a multi-room audio setup using Ubuntu 22.04 and Shairport Sync.

I have the following `.asoundrc` to create virtual devices that I can use in Shairport Sync (or any other source supporting ALSA):

```
pcm.stereoA {
    # 0 - Front Left
    # 1 - Front Right
    type route;
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0";
    slave.channels 8;
    ttable.0.0 1;
    ttable.1.1 1;
}

pcm.stereoB {
    # 2 - Front Center
    # 3 - LFE
    type route;
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0";
    slave.channels 8;
    ttable.0.3 1;
    ttable.1.2 1;
}

pcm.stereoC {
    # 4 - Rear Right
    # 5 - Rear Left
    type route;
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0";
    slave.channels 8;
    ttable.0.4 1;
    ttable.1.5 1;
}

pcm.stereoD {
    # 6 - Side Right
    # 7 - Side Left
    type route;
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0";
    slave.channels 8;
    ttable.0.7 1;
    ttable.1.6 1;
}
```

The problem now is that this only works for `stereoA`. For the other outputs, the audio remains silent when being used through Shairport Sync.

However, it works fine when being tested with speaker-test:

```
speaker-test -D stereoB -c 2

speaker-test 1.2.6

Playback device is stereoB
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 12 to 96000
Period size range from 6 to 48000
Using max buffer size 96000
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 24000
was set buffer_size = 96000
 1 - Front Center
 0 - LFE
```

I can here the test noise being played on the correct outputs.

Shairport Sync actually also accepts the audio stream when being told to use stereoB as its output_device and looks as if it’s playing (also the audio device is busy when I try to play something else). So my guess it’s that it’s playing on the wrong channels.

How can I fix the channel mapping so that the stereo pairs actually behave like real stereo pairs and are named Front Left and Front Right?

Comment: If that's a true 7.1 system, you can't split it quite this way. There's 7 main speakers + subwoofer. Right now your StereoB is configured to output the theater's front center channel and the subwoofer - this won't sound very nice on a pair of stereo speakers on another room. If you want stereo on a different room, you need to send front R/L channels there as well as your theater system - that's the closest you get to 2 channel stereo with this system. The rest of the channels are one way or another effected, as their purpose is to create the immersive sound of a movie theater.

Comment: My understanding is that this is actually a 8 channel sound card and the 7.1 surround stuff is done in software. I could be wrong. But I’ll check how the output with the Center and the Sub sounds to make sure. To my initial question, I just found out that the config is actually working. I think when reconnecting to Shairport Sync, the volume was reduced and I didn’t notice.

Comment: LOL, "is it plugged in" et co. are still valid questions :-D You're right, the 7.1 is done in Terratech Audio Center. Thx for this, looks like an interesting box. I remember Terratech from early 90s being much touted as The Soundcard Of Choice for Those In The Know, didn't even know they're still around :-)

Comment: Well, I was ~6 in the early 90s, but I remember having a Terratec sound card in my first PC in the late 90s. The logo (which I believe they haven’t changed ever since) has some strong retro vibes for me!

Comment: I was practically drooling after a Terratec card, having my first PC, making music with Trackers. Too expensive at the time for a youngster fresh outta the army, just old enuff to drink legally :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my config is actually working perfectly fine. I just didn’t realize that macOS is resetting the volume slider to a fairly low volume when switching between AirPlay targets, which is why I hadn’t heard the audio when testing the different outputs.

What I learned along the way is that you can slightly streamline the config by defining a `pcm_slave` section and referencing it in the `pcm` sections.

So I’m leaving my updated config here in case anybody finds it useful:

```
pcm_slave.outs {
    pcm "hw:1,0";
    channels 8;
}

pcm.stereoA {
    type route;
    slave outs;
    ttable.0.0 1;
    ttable.1.1 1;
}

pcm.stereoB {
    type route;
    slave outs;
    ttable.0.3 1;
    ttable.1.2 1;
}

pcm.stereoC {
    type route;
    slave outs;
    ttable.0.4 1;
    ttable.1.5 1;
}

pcm.stereoD {
    type route;
    slave outs;
    ttable.0.6 1;
    ttable.1.7 1;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Next time maybe put the OS in the question :-)

Comment: Thanks :-) I just added it!